# Calling an ImageView variable inside an if statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I'm using `Swift` in `Xcode` and that's my issue:

I want to declare a variable where I want to store an `UIImageView` (Not an `UIImage`, but an `UIImageView`), so I tried something like that

```
var nameVariable = UIImageView()
```

Then I need to recall this nameVariable inside an if statement

```
    if(\(nameVariable).center.y > something){..}
```

I tried using "(nameVariable)" but it doesn't work, can you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work ? Did it gave you any error ?

Comment: @Alessandro Giovagnoli be careful when you write programming code syntax in your questions

Comment: @Alessandro Giovagnoli - Welcome to SO. Yes, but you must write in english please, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Declare Variable**

```
var img=UIImageView()
```

**Then use it**

```
if img.center.y > 50 {  
 //do stuff here           
}
```

Comment: Ah, easier than i thought. Thanks!